# Posting form sends route values as querystring instead of url segments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When posting a form using @Html.BeginForm the route values in the url generated are sent as querystrings rather than url segments, leading to incorrect routing.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Add-Supplier/{id}/{supplierId}")]
[ActionName("Add-Supplier")]
public ActionResult AddSupplier(int id, int supplierId)
{
    rmPurchaseOrder purchaseOrder = rmPurchaseOrder.Load(id);
    if (purchaseOrder != null)
    {
        purchaseOrder.SupplierId = supplierId;
        purchaseOrder.Save();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Purchase-Order", new { id });
}
```

razor (cshtml):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add-Supplier", "Purchase-Orders", new { id = Model.PurchaseOrderId, supplierId = Model.SupplierId }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="form-group stMarTop10">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SupplierId, new { @class = "label label-default" })
        @(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SupplierId, Model.SupplierSelectListItems, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control wdef" })
    </div>
}
```

The url generated by the form post with this code is:

/Add-Supplier/3777?supplierId=25

Whereas I want it to be:

/Add-Supplier/3777/25

Any help appreciated, thanks...

Comment: With the code you shared, the `SupplierId` value will be send in Form Data, not the URL, when you make a selection in the SELECT element.

Comment: The route `/Add-Supplier/3777/25` makes no sense. We cannot tell what it means by looking at it. Of course if we look at your code we'll know that it means `Add-Supplier/{id}/{supplierId}`, but routes should be easily readable and meaningful without looking at the code. I recommend changing your routing to the standard way, but if you want to continue with it, you'll have to do many things manually as the framework is not designed for that.

Comment: Thanks Racil. You could well be right that the framework is not designed for this. Shashi's answer does do the trick though. I disagree that the url should have any place in making things easier for the developer - it's user facing. If the user thinks they understand the url they might try to hack it, so better to keep it obtuse (and concise). Also this is backend so there are no SEO considerations. Developers can see the code and gain understanding there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps:

Step 1: Write route in the config file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Segment",
  url: "Add-Supplier/{id}/{id1}",
  defaults: new 
  { 
    controller = "Your controller Name", 
    action = "Your Action Name", 
    id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
    id1 = UrlParameter.Optional
  }
);
```

Step 2: Replace your action method with the below method.

```
public ActionResult AddSupplier(int id, int id1)
{

}
```